# Kile fails to start ConTexT

Tags: context, kile

Windows 7 64bit, Kile 2.9.60 with default settings and ConText mkiv.
Trying to compile a test document:

```
\starttext
\startsection[title={Testing ConTeXt}]
This is my first ConTeXt document.
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

I note that I am able to compile this correctly in the DOS prompt (using `context hello.tex`). Kile uses these settings:

> texexec --pdf --nonstopmode %source

and when I click on the ConTexT compile button it says

> [ConTexT] hello.tex => hello.pdf (texexec)
>
> [ConTexT] failed to start

I understand that this should not work, since there seems to be no texexec file on my system anywhere. So I tried changing the command to `context` in settings, but Kile does not allow me to remove the arguments (restores them if removed). The results with the command changed to `context` are the same as above. What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`texexec` is the the older, unmaintained ConTeXt version, called ConTeXt MKII. `context` is the the newer, underdevelopment version of ConTeXt, called MKIV. You need to tell Kile to use `context` instead of `texexec`.

Probably call `context %source` from the look of it.